# ng-Bootstrap Datepicker popup in a table not showing correctly

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ngb-datepicker

I have a ng-bootstrap datepicker in a table. The table is needed for a clear layout on the web site.

If i clicked on the button, then the popup is still showing like the table-height is. I tried so much and know I hope somebody has a solution for me.

```
<div id="tbl1" class="table-responsive" style="">
<table class="table table-sm" style="font-size: small">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="border: hidden">
            <td style="width: 25%">Contract begin</td>
            <td style="width: 25%">Contract end</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border: hidden;">
            <td>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
                                    <img src="img/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;"/>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>2001-01-01</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Demo in Plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/ELBO2IA0YUtdzRMe)

Comment: kindly add more information on the issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is that `.table-responsive` uses `overflow-x: auto` which makes your datepicker to be showed only inside your div.

The solution would be to add `overflow: visible` to `#tbl1` in order to display the datepicker outside the limits.

[Here is](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/iwFzasG3cjaSI7Nz) the updated plunker with this approach.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah, okay that‘s true. Thanks a lot for your help 

Comment: `overflow: visible` will remove table scrolling feature. If table has lot of columns, this solution will break the scrolling.